# DELPHI : What is the best way to compress max and to keep quility of BITMAP

Tags: delphi, bitmap, compression, image-compression

I have a function that I made for compressing bitmap to JPEG.

```
procedure BmptoJpeg(Bmp : TBitmap; JpgStream: TStream);
var
  Jpg: TJPEGImage;
begin
  Jpg := TJPEGImage.Create;
  try
    Jpg.Assign(Bmp);
    Jpg.CompressionQuality := 10;
    Jpg.Compress;
    Jpg.SaveToStream(JpgStream);

  finally
    Jpg.Free;
  end;

end;
```

But this is not suitable for good quality of Original Bitmap.
Is there another way to keep quality and to compress max Bitmap?
Another method without compressing to JPEG is also good for me..
Only compressing max and keeping quality is my target

Comment: same question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102043/problem-converting-bmp-to-jpg-using-tjpegimage-component

Comment: `Jpg.CompressionQuality := 10;`  ? Try `100`

Comment: Well, what do you want to do? Do you want lossy JPEG compression? Do you want lossless PNG compression? Any decision is going to rely on knowledge of the content of the image which only you have. Different algorithms are better or worse suited to different image types.

Comment: You've said "compress it by 90%", which means "throw away most of the data". What do you expect but poor quality when you do so?

Answer (score 0):

I would say to use PNGs instead (which can be lossy or lossless), but it turns out I've had real problems with bugs with them in newer versions of Delphi relating to Alpha.  Bitmaps don't support Alpha anyway though so... go figure.

But assuming you want to keep it a TBitmap at its core, and assuming you're using a not terribly outdated version of Delphi, 
you can compress the bitmap using TCompressionStream. TCompressionStream can be used on any kind of data actually and used in conjuction with TFileStream or TMemoryStream or any other kind of TStream derivative for the most part.

For this you'll create a TCompressionStream object and use TBitmap.SaveToSTream() to save the bitmap to the TCompressionStream.  The result will be a lossless version of your bitmap data.